# PictureBox from a List not visible

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm currently working on a kind of train-dispatching game in c# where the "maps" with the trains, tracks, signals etc. are stored in .txt files and visualised by PictureBoxes in specific locations.
As I tried to build the first debug map (just 4 tracks in a square) I see no tracks(PictureBoxes) although I get no Exception or anything.
I added the tracks (german: "gleis") under properties->resources, the name logic of them are that bgleis ("besetztes gleis" = occupied track) are the ones with trains on them, then comes the lenght of the track in px (at this time there is only 60 and 100) and the "v" or "h" for vertical or horizontal tracks

The Code (Variable names etc. in german, sorry for that)
Line 58 and following is, where the tracks getting loaded.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<Zug> ZuegeListe = new List<Zug>();
        public List<Signal> SignaleListe = new List<Signal>();
        public List<Gleis> GleiseListe = new List<Gleis>();
        public List<PictureBox> BildBoxenListe = new List<PictureBox>();
        public PictureBox BildBox = new PictureBox();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //the following happens, when the player starts a new game (TODO: browse files for "maps" txt's)
        private void neuesSpielStartenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string zeiletext;
            System.IO.StreamReader map =
                new System.IO.StreamReader("C: /Users/Tristan/Desktop/Bahnspiel/kartedebug.txt");

           while((zeiletext = map.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //checking, which type of object (track, train, signal...) is now getting loaded
                switch (zeiletext)
                {
                    //trains, note that they are not displayed by PicBoxes, for now they are just there 
                    case "Zug":
                        string lesezeileZug;
                        int sollIDZug;
                        int sollLauf;

                        lesezeileZug = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileZug, out sollIDZug);

                        lesezeileZug = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileZug, out sollLauf);

                        ZuegeListe.Add(new Zug(sollIDZug, sollLauf) );

                        //Debug Output of each
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Zug: " + sollIDZug + " " + sollLauf);
                        break;

                        //tracks, here is the problem with the PictureBoxes
                    case "Gleis":
                        string lesezeileGleis;
                        int sollIDGleis;
                        int sollPositionGleisX;
                        int sollPositionGleisY;
                        int sollLaengeGleis;
                        int sollAusrichtungGleis;
                        int sollBesetzung;
                        int sollReisezeit;
                        int sollVerbindungGle1;
                        int sollVerbindungGle2;

                        lesezeileGleis = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileGleis, out sollIDGleis);

                        lesezeileGleis = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileGleis, out sollPositionGleisX);

                        lesezeileGleis = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileGleis, out sollPositionGleisY);

                        lesezeileGleis = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileGleis, out sollLaengeGleis);

                        lesezeileGleis = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileGleis, out sollAusrichtungGleis);

                        lesezeileGleis = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileGleis, out sollBesetzung);

                        lesezeileGleis = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileGleis, out sollReisezeit);

                        lesezeileGleis = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileGleis, out sollVerbindungGle1);

                        lesezeileGleis = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileGleis, out sollVerbindungGle2);

                        //Einzelgleis in Gleisliste speichern
                        GleiseListe.Add(new Gleis(sollIDGleis, sollPositionGleisX, sollPositionGleisY,
                            sollLaengeGleis, sollAusrichtungGleis, sollBesetzung, sollReisezeit, sollVerbindungGle1, sollVerbindungGle2));

                        //BildBoxFeeding: Location
                        BildBox.Location = new Point(sollPositionGleisX, sollPositionGleisY);

                        //BildBoxFeeding: Bild Vertical/Horizontal + Occupation + Size
                        if (sollAusrichtungGleis == 0 && sollBesetzung == 0) //Vertical free
                        {
                            switch (sollLaengeGleis)
                            {
                                case 60:
                                    BildBox.ImageLocation = "/sprites/gleis60v.png";
                                    BildBox.Size = new Size(5,60);
                                    break;
                                case 100:
                                    BildBox.ImageLocation = "/sprites/gleis100v.png";
                                    BildBox.Size = new Size(5, 100);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fehler: Falsche Laengenangaben bei Gleis vertikal");
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (sollAusrichtungGleis == 0 && sollBesetzung != 0) //Vertical occupied
                        {
                            switch (sollLaengeGleis)
                            {
                                case 60:
                                    BildBox.ImageLocation = "/sprites/bgleis60v.png";
                                    BildBox.Size = new Size(5, 60);
                                    break;
                                case 100:
                                    BildBox.ImageLocation = "/sprites/bgleis100v.png";
                                    BildBox.Size = new Size(5, 100);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fehler: Falsche Laengenangaben bei besetztem Gleis vertikal");
                                    break;
                            }

                        }
                        else if (sollAusrichtungGleis == 1 && sollBesetzung == 0) // Horizontal Free
                        {
                            switch (sollLaengeGleis)
                            {
                                case 60:
                                    BildBox.ImageLocation = "/sprites/gleis60h.png";
                                    BildBox.Size = new Size(5, 60);
                                    break;
                                case 100:
                                    BildBox.ImageLocation = "/sprites/gleis100h.png";
                                    BildBox.Size = new Size(5, 100);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fehler: Falsche Laengenangaben bei Gleis horizontal");
                                    break;

                            }
                        }
                        else if (sollAusrichtungGleis == 1 && sollBesetzung != 0) // Horizontal occupied
                        {
                            switch (sollLaengeGleis)
                            {
                                case 60:
                                    BildBox.ImageLocation = "/sprites/bgleis60h.png";
                                    BildBox.Size = new Size(5, 60);
                                    break;
                                case 100:
                                    BildBox.ImageLocation = "/sprites/bgleis100h.png";
                                    BildBox.Size = new Size(5, 100);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fehler: Falsche Laengenangaben bei besetztem Gleis horizontal");
                                    break;

                            }
                        }

                        BildBoxenListe.Add(BildBox);

                            //Debug Output of each
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Gleis: ID: " + sollIDGleis + ", Besetzung: " + sollBesetzung + ", Reisezeit: " + sollReisezeit + ", Verb.1: " + sollVerbindungGle1 + ", Verb.2: " + sollVerbindungGle2);
                        break;

                    case "Signal":
                        string lesezeileSig;
                        int sollIDSig;
                        int sollSignalbild;
                        int sollPositionSignalX;
                        int sollPositionSignalY;
                        int sollAusrichtungSignal;
                        int sollVerbindungSig1;
                        int sollVerbindungSig2;

                        lesezeileSig = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileSig, out sollIDSig);

                        lesezeileSig = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileSig, out sollPositionSignalX);

                        lesezeileSig = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileSig, out sollPositionSignalY);

                        lesezeileSig = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileSig, out sollAusrichtungSignal);

                        lesezeileSig = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileSig, out sollSignalbild);

                        lesezeileSig = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileSig, out sollVerbindungSig1);

                        lesezeileSig = map.ReadLine();
                        Int32.TryParse(lesezeileSig, out sollVerbindungSig2);

                        SignaleListe.Add(new Signal(sollIDSig, sollPositionSignalX, sollPositionSignalY, sollAusrichtungSignal, sollSignalbild, sollVerbindungSig1, sollVerbindungSig2));
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                foreach (PictureBox picbox in BildBoxenListe){
                    picbox.Visible = true;
                }


            }

            map.Close();

        }
    }

    public class Zug
    {
        private int IDZug;
        private int Lauf;

        public Zug(int sollIDZug, int sollLauf)
        {
            this.IDZug = sollIDZug;
            this.Lauf = sollLauf;
        }

    }

    public class Gleis
    {
        public int IDGleis;
        public int PositionGleisX;
        public int PositionGleisY;
        public int LaengeGleis;
        public int AusrichtungGleis;
        public int BesetzungGleis;
        public int ReisezeitGleis;
        public int Verbindung1Gleis;
        public int Verbindung2Gleis;

        public Gleis(int sollIDGleis, int sollPositionGleisX, int sollPositionGleisY, int sollLaengeGleis, int sollAusrichtungGleis, int sollBesetzung, int sollReisezeit, int sollVerbindung1, int sollVerbindung2)
        {
            this.IDGleis = sollIDGleis;
            this.PositionGleisX = sollPositionGleisX;
            this.PositionGleisY = sollPositionGleisY;
            this.LaengeGleis = sollLaengeGleis;
            this.AusrichtungGleis = sollAusrichtungGleis;
            this.BesetzungGleis = sollBesetzung;
            this.ReisezeitGleis = sollReisezeit;
            this.Verbindung1Gleis = sollVerbindung1;
            this.Verbindung2Gleis = sollVerbindung2;
        }
    }

    public class Signal
    {
        //Verbindung1 is the one, the signal is readible of
        private int IDSig;
        private int PositionSignalX;
        private int PositionSignalY;
        private int AusrichtungSignal;
        private int SigBild;
        private int Verbindung1;
        private int Verbindung2;

        public Signal(int sollIDSig, int sollPositionSignalX, int sollPositionSignalY, int sollAusrichtungSignal, int sollSigBild, int sollVerbindung1, int sollVerbindung2)
        {
            this.IDSig = sollIDSig;
            this.PositionSignalX = sollPositionSignalX;
            this.PositionSignalY = sollPositionSignalY;
            this.AusrichtungSignal = sollAusrichtungSignal;
            this.SigBild = sollSigBild;
            this.Verbindung1 = sollVerbindung1;
            this.Verbindung2 = sollVerbindung2;
        }
    }

}
```

thanks a lot in advance!
and sorry for my bad english and/or if I did any noob errors, I learning c# only for 2 Weeks now

Comment: This is a fine question if not too much code is put. You could snapshot where you think the problematic area is and put it (apart from the full code) too, I think. This way, the answerer will find it easy to locate the problem.

Comment: You wrote a bunch of code to parse the file and completely forgot to take care of the visual representation.  There is only *one* picture box, you need many.  And you can never see it since you did not add it to the form, this.Controls.Add() required.  You'll need to go much slower, leave the file for version 2.